# windows like clipboard manager for linux?

Tags: clipboard-manager

is there a windows like clipboard manager available for Linux with shortcut Mod+v which pops on mouse context menu also it should support images in clipboard?

Comment: It can be integrated in the desktop manager (there is one in KDE, for instance).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`diodon` supports context menu and images also.

```
sudo apt install diodon
```

i3 config for shortcut

```
bindsym $mod+Shift+w  exec diodon
```

**Update 1:**

Simple clipboard manager to be integrated with rofi - Static binary available
https://github.com/erebe/greenclip

Answer (score 2):

Won't say about windows like but, did you checked ClipIt? `ctrl+alt+h` will give you a list and a systray icon for more options and configurations.

[image]

Update: ClipIt on Ubuntu 20.04 is broken. Patch is now merged to master branch and it was tagged as 1.4.5. Now it need to be packaged for Debian and Ubuntu. 
Until then use 1.4.2 version (from 18.04) or patched version from my ppa:
https://launchpad.net/~afelinczak/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: it's not showing history on mouse menu when clicked Ctrl+alt+H

Comment: Check `Preferences` -> `Hotkeys` if keys are set properly or not.

Comment: uninstall parcellite if you have it  as it's hot key is also ctrl+alt+h?

Answer (score 1):

There is a extension called Clipboard Indicator. I use it and it's great

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/779/clipboard-indicator/

Comment: yes...but like parcellite its not support mouse context menu...